# passing php variable in javascript function

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I am new to php and javscript.I am working on some project of question and answer system.I want to send question id to javascript  function.

here is my php code

```
<?php   
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $p = $row["description"] ;
        echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction(<?= $p ?>)" align="left" class="j" role="group" aria-label="..."  >                                       <button id = "btnl<?=$i?>"  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round" style="border-radius:10px;">';
        echo $i;
        echo '</button>';
        echo '<p class="question" style ="display:inline; ">';
        echo $p;
        echo '</p>';
        echo '</div>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

My javacript function is:

```
<script>
function myOverFunction(x) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("btnl"+x).style.backgroundColor = "#d9534f";
}
</script>
```

my code does not working ..please help me ...

Comment: Does not work how? Do you get any errors? What does inspecting the div's code tell you?

Comment: My javascript function does not getting value from php code..please see to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction(<?= $p ?>)"
```

Change it to:

```
echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction('. $p .')".
```

Same goes for the other occurrences.
You can't `echo` from inside an `echo`

Your final `echo` should look like this:

```
 echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction(\''. $p .'\')" align="left" class="j" role="group" aria-label="..."  >                                       <button id = "btnl'.$i.'"  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round" style="border-radius:10px;">';
```

Note:  If `$p` is a string, it needs quotes. And quotes inside quotes need escaping

Comment: My javascript function does not getting value from php code..please see to it

Comment: try `myOverFunction(\''. $p .'\')`. If `$p` is a string, it needs quotes. And quotes inside quotes need escaping

Comment: still myOverFunction(\''. $p .'\')  not changing innerHTML of "demo"

Comment: Can you post a view-source line of `<div onclick="myOver...` ?

Comment: echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction(\''. $p .'\')" align="left" class="j" role="group" aria-label="..."  > <button id = "btnl'.$i.'"  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round" style="border-radius:10px;">'.$i.'</button><p class="question" style ="display:inline; ">'.$p.'</p></div>';                                                                                                         ******* javascrpit  function ****                                                                  function myOverFunction(\''. $p .'\') {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$p";     }

Comment: no, i mean the generated html. the one you can inspect in the browser. better yet, paste your entire html source page here: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Please see line no. 154 to 165 and 325 to 331 ....            http://pastebin.com/yEQV0sYg

Comment: That is not evaluating the php code. Are you using a webserver? If you're on win, checkout Wamp or Xampp, or any other web server. Your url should then be something like `http://localhost/page.php`. If you do have a web server setup, try renaming the page to .php if it's currently .html

Comment: Also, lines 325 to 331 should be `function myOverFunction(x) {}` exactly like the one you posted in the question. That one doesn't need escaping. and `console.log(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking this line by trying to re-open php tags within the echo:

```
echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction(<?= $p ?>)" align="left" class="j" role="group" aria-label="..."  > <button id = "btnl<?=$i?>"  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round" style="border-radius:10px;">';
```

Try this:

```
echo '<div onclick="myOverFunction('.$p.')" align="left" class="j" role="group" aria-label="..."  > <button id = "btnl'.$i.'"  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round" style="border-radius:10px;">';
```

Comment: My javascript function does not getting value from php code..please see to it

Comment: onClick it changes nothing